# how to add dynamic content to a layout page MVC4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application in MVC4.  I have a layout page that displays the logged in user etc.  There are background processes that run.  If any of these fail, I need to alert the user.

So I thought I would add an error symbol in the layout page(as this displayed in every page) if an error has occurred.  I would know if an error has occurred by a flag set in a table in the database.

How can I access that in my layout page?

or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the user to be alerted to events that are running on the server WITHOUT doing a post back (and refreshing the page) and WITHOUT the user having to click a "Check for alerts" button (or something similar), then here are some options:

- Run a constant polling method clientside (Javascript) that checks for serverside data/flags on a regular basis
- Use real time communication between the server and your client. Since this is an MVC application, [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) is the way to go

From the [SignalR website](http://www.asp.net/signalr),

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available.

I'd definitely recommend SignalR for handling something like this, and it's incredibly easy to use. Essentially, you'll have your serverside process(es) let your SignalR class (known as a hub) know that something has happened. In turn, the hub sends that information to your client side Javascript. End result is that the user will be alerted, in realtime, when anything (of your choosing) happens serverside.